# How to test a controller with RSpec using a custom url

Tags: rspec

I'm trying to test my `SessionsCotroller` and have written the following:

```
   describe "POST create session" do 
        it "should create a new session" do
            params = { session: { email: 'email@example.com', password: 'foobar' } }
            post '/api/signin', params
            response['success'] == true
        end

        ...
    end
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
Failure/Error: post '/api/signin', params
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"/api/signin", :controller=>"sessions", :session=>{:email=>"email@example.com", :password=>"foobar"}}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: is the custom URL in your `routes.rb` file? Have you tried mocking the requests? (Webmock)

Comment: Yes, the URL is in `routes.rb` and I don't know how to mock the requests... Would you be able to give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use request specs for the purpose

spec/requests/api_v1_spec.rb

```
require "rails_helper"
RSpec.describe "Create Session", :type => :request do
  describe "POST create session" do 
    it "should create a new session" do
        params = { session: { email: 'email@example.com',password:'foobar' } }
        post '/api/signin', params
        response['success'] == true
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The methods `get` and `post` are described in the [Guide to Testing Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) under "Functional Tests for Your Controllers". They take these arguments:

> - The action of the controller you are requesting. This can be in the form of a string or a symbol.
> - An optional hash of request parameters to pass into the action (eg. query string parameters or article variables).
> - An optional hash of session variables to pass along with the request.
> - An optional hash of flash values.

`params` and `session` are separate hashes, e.g.:

```
session = {token: "string"}
params = {thing_id: "123"}

post :action, params, session
```